# C++ cost of default constructors for string, list, vector

Tags: c++, performance, stl

In many cases I would like to pass reference to const string parameter with default being empty string.

```
void func(std::string const& z = std::string());
```

I am wondering how expensive is calling default constructor vs. passing reference to some static empty string?

```
void func(std::string const& z = my_staticEmptyStr);
```

What about lists and vectors?

Update. Unfortunately, I do not see a nice generic way to have static empty-xxx objects, except having its own copy in every class that needs it. Fortunately, it seems to me that none of the default constructors for stl classes require memory allocations, so I decided to do it in a traditional way on all paths except frequently called ones.

Comment: `list` is probably the only one of any significant overhead, it's possible your library implementation will dynamically allocate a sentinel node (the one `end()` points to) upon default construction. But the only sure way to find out what the cost is is to profile your implementation.

Comment: Are you trying to implement optional parameters?

Comment: @MM7, yet and my question was reformatted in the strange way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am wondering how expensive is calling default constructor vs passing reference to some `static` empty string?

If you have a `static` empty string, it is better to use it. Constructing a new object and destructing it is going to cost some time, however small it may be.

You don't lose anything by using the `static` empty string if construction and destruction of a default constructed `std::string` does not take any time at all.

You potentially gain quite a bit of time over the life of the program depending on how may times the function gets called if a default constructed `std::string` takes even a small amount of time in the constructor and the destructor.

Comment: Function calls can be inlined, so the call itself may not be a major factor.

Comment: If your `string` implementation doesn't malloc, it should be pretty fast. However, I found that some standard library containers always malloc, and that can have a large effect on runtime if you call it often enough.

Comment: @KerrekSB, I was including any overheads associated with dynamic memory allocation and deallocation when was saying *function call*. Point taken though.

Comment: @RSahu: Yeah - whether there are non-allocating default constructors is QoI.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the implementation. If the string in your standard library uses the "small string optimization" (which most modern libraries do), `string`s default constructor might be as small as three instructions. (zeroing three words).

`vector` and `list` can also be very cheap to initialize, but it depends on the implementation.